# How to join tables creating a new row if it doesn't exist

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How to join tables creating a new row if it doesn't exist.

I tried: `Products.join(Class, Products.id_product == Class.id_product, 'right')`

```
Products
+-----------+-------+----------+-----------+
|day        | store | quantity | id_product|
|2022-05-05 | 01    | 10       | 1         |
|2022-05-05 | 01    | 10       | 2         |
|2022-05-05 | 01    | 7        | 3         |
|2022-05-22 | 01    | 8        | 1         |
+-----------+-------+----------+-----------+


Class
+-----------+-----+
|id_product | size|
|1          | S   |
|2          | L   |
|3          | XL  |
+-----------+-----+
```

I would like new rows to be created with null value for quantity of stock, but keeping the information of day, store, id_product and size.

```
My result
+-----------+-------+----------+------------+-----+
|day        | store | quantity | id_product | size|
|2022-05-05 | 01    | 10       | 1          | S   |
|2022-05-05 | 01    | 10       | 2          | L   |
|2022-05-05 | 01    | 7        | 3          | XL  |
|2022-05-22 | 01    | 8        | 1          | S   |  
+-----------+-------+----------+------------+-----+

Expected
+-----------+-------+----------+------------+-----+
|day        | store | quantity | id_product | size|
|2022-05-05 | 01    | 10       | 1          | S   |
|2022-05-05 | 01    | 10       | 2          | L   |
|2022-05-05 | 01    | 7        | 3          | XL  |
|2022-05-22 | 01    | 8        | 1          | S   |
|2022-05-22 | 01    | null     | 2          | L   |
|2022-05-22 | 01    | null     | 3          | XL  |
+-----------+-------+----------+------------+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

Guess you need to first have all combinations of day, store, product and size and then outer join with products.

```
products
    .select($"day", $"store")
    .distinct
    .crossJoin(classes)
    .as("keys")
    .join(
        products.as("prds"), 
        Seq("day", "store", "id_product"),
        "left"
    )
    .select(
        $"keys.day", $"keys.store", $"prds.quantity", 
        $"keys.id_product", $"keys.size"
    )
```